# Can you save a draft for your store listing in the google play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an existing app. I want to update the copy to prepare for my next build, but my next build's apk is not ready to be uploaded yet. Can I update the copy and save it without publishing the copy changes to the publicly visible play store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, it looks like drafts have been added (more or less) to the Google Play developer console in late 2015.  They introduced "Timed Updates" which allow you to go through the entire publish process (including updating copy) without actually pushing the update.  After the update is processed, there will be a "Go Live" button, which you can use to actually push live at your discretion.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=en
http://readwrite.com/2015/10/29/android-apps-timed-publishing/

Answer (score 11):

Not at the current date. There is only one copy of the store listing, so any changes you apply to it go live as you save them.

Comment: This is the correct answer and you should consider marking it as Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

In the Play store you can found a feature which allow you to release your app to a limited number to people or testers

Read here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en